# Creating R package using code from script file

Tags: r, r-package

I’ve written some R functions and dropped them into a script file using RStudio. These are bits of code that I use over and over, so I’m wondering how I might most easily create an R package out of them (for my own private use).

I’ve read various “how to” guides online but they’re quite complicated. Can anyone suggest an “idiot’s guide” to doing this please?

Comment: https://r-pkgs.org/ is as easy as it gets, I’m afraid. There’s some complexity that can’t really be removed from the process. That said, for a *very incomplete* simple introduction, check out [Hilary Parker’s tutorial](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/).

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been involved in creating R packages recently, so I can help you with that. Before proceeding to the steps to be followed, there are some pre-requisites, which include:

- RStudio
- devtools package (for most of the functions involved in creation of a package)
- roxygen2 package (for roxygen documentation)

In case you don't have the aforementioned packages, you can install them with these commands respectively:

`install.packages("devtools")`

`install.packages("roxygen2")`

Steps:

**(1)** Import devtools in RStudio by using `library(devtools)`.

(devtools is a core package that makes creating R packages easier with its tools)

**(2)** Create your package by using:

`create_package("~/directory/package_name")` for a custom directory.

or

`create_package("package_name")` if you want your package to be created in current workspace directory.

**(3)** Soon after you execute this function, it will open a new RStudio session. You will observe that in the old session some lines will be auto-generated which basically tells R to create a new package with required components in the specified directory.

After this, we are done with this old instance of RStudio. We will continue our work on the new RStudio session window.

By far the package creation part is already over (yes, that simple) however, a package isn't directly functionable just by its creation plus the fact that you need to include a function in it requires some additional aspects of a package such as its documentation (where the function's title, parameters, return types, examples etc as mentioned using `@param`, `@return` etc - you would be familiar if you see roxygen documentation like in some github repositories) and `R CMD` checks to get it working.

I'll get to that in the subsequent steps, but just in case you want to verify that your package is created, you can look at:

- The top right corner of the new RStudio session, where you can see the package name that you created.
- The console, where you will see that R created a new directory/folder in the path that we specified in `create_package()` function.
- The files panel of RStudio session, where you'll notice a bunch of new files and directories within your directory.

**(4)** As you mentioned in your words, you drop your functions in a script file - hence you will need to create the script first, which can be done using:

`use_r("function_name")`

A new R script will pop up in your working session, ready to be used.
Now go ahead and write your function(s) in it.

**(5)** After your done, you need to load the function(s) you have written for your package. This is accomplished by using the `devtools::load_all()` function.

When you execute `load_all()` in the console, you'll get to know that the functions have been loaded into your package when you'll see `Loading package_name` displayed in console.
You can try calling your functions after that in the console to verify that they work as a part of the package.

**(6)** Now that your function has been written and loaded into your package, it is time to move onto checks. It is a good practice to check the whole package as we make changes to our package. The function `devtools::check()` offers an easy way to do this.

Try executing `check()` in the console, it will go through a number of procedures checking your package for warnings/errors and give details for the same as messages on the screen (pertaining to what are the errors/warnings/notes). The `R CMD check` results at the end will contain the vital logs for you to see what are the errors and warnings you got along with their frequency.

If the functions in your package are written well, (with additional package dependencies taken care of) it will give you two warnings upon execution of `check`:

The first warning will be regarding the license that your package uses, which is not specified for a new pacakge.

The second should be the one for documentation, warning us that our code is not documented.

To resolve the first issue which is the license, use the `use_mit_license("license_holder_name")` command (or any other license which suits your package - but then for private use as you mentioned, it doesn't really matter what you specify if only your going to use it or not its to be distributed) with your name as in place of `license_holder_name` or anything which suits a license name.
This will add the license field in the `.DESCRIPTION` file (in your files panel) plus create additional files adding the license information.

Also you'll need to edit the `.DESCRIPTION` file, which have self-explanatory fields to fill-in or edit. Here is an example of how you can have it:

```r
Package: Your_package_name
Title: Give a brief title
Version: 1.0.0.0
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "Your_first_name",
           family = "Your_surname/family_name",
           role = c("package_creator", "author"),
           email = "youremailaddress@gmail.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: Give a brief description considering your package functionality.
License: will be updated with whatever license you provide, the above step will take care of this line.
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
```

To resolve the documentation warning, you'll need to document your function using roxygen documentation. An example:

```r
#' @param a parameter one
#' @param b parameter two
#' @return sum of a and b
#' @export
#'
#' @examples 
#' yourfunction(1,2)
yourfunction <- function(a,b)
{
  sum <- a+b
  return(sum)
}
```

Follow the roxygen syntax and add attributes as you desire, some may be optional such as `@title` for specifying title, while others such as `@import` are required (must) if your importing from other packages other than base R.

After your done documenting your function(s) using the Roxygen skeleton, we can tell our package that we have documented our functions by running `devtools::document()`. After you execute the `document()` command, perform `check()` again to see if you get any warnings. If you don't, then that means you're good to go. (you won't if you follow the steps)

Lastly, you'll need to install the package, for it to be accessible by R. Simply use the `install()` command (yes the same one you used at the beginning, except you don't need to specify the package here like `install("package")` since you are currently working in an instance where the package is loaded and is ready to be deployed/installed) and you'll see after a few lines of installation a statement like "Done (package_name)", which indicates the installation of our package is complete.

Now you can try your function by first importing your package using `library("package_name")` and then calling your desired function from the package. Thats it, congrats you did it!

I've tried to include the procedure in a lucid way (the way I create my R packages), but if you have any doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write such a thorough response - it’s very much appreciated. I will try this out soon.